# How to check input field pattern validation on if else condition javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to check input field pattern validation on if else condition javascript? to show message div for valid and Invalid  on button submit on type for pattern  validation?

```js
function myFunction(element) {

  if (document.getElementById("smsno").value.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("sms_ntvalidate").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("sms_validate").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sms_validate").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("sms_ntvalidate").style.display = "none";

  }

}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
                                    
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 smsForm">
                    <label for="contact1">SMS No.<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="smsno" id="smsno"
                        placeholder="SMS No." pattern="^(00|\+)[1-9]{1}([0-9][\s]*){9,16}$"
                        required onkeyup="myFunction(this)" />
                    <div class="custm-valid" id="sms_validate" style="display:none;">Valid.</div>
                    <div class="custm-invalid" id="sms_ntvalidate" style="display:none;">Please enter valid contact no.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 whatsappForm">
                    <label for="contact2">WhatsApp No.<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="whtspno" id="whtspno"
                        placeholder="WhatsApp No." pattern="^(00|\+)[1-9]{1}([0-9][\s]*){9,16}$"
                        required  />
                    <div class="custm-valid" id="whts_validate"style="display:none;">Valid.</div>
                    <div class="custm-invalid" id="whts_ntvalidate" style="display:none;">Please enter valid contact no.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you copied the correct JS/HTML in to the question? None of the ids in the JS exist in the HTML...?

Comment: Hi @Rory , sorry by mistack it was there I have modified it. You can check now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is number you can use custom js for thise validation like
`document.getElementById("smsno").value.forEach((value)=>{ if(value >== 0 &&  value <== 9) { // Condition} else { //Wrong Pattern condition } );`

The forEach checkes the every single element on input